# An SqlParameter with ParameterName is not contained by this SqlParameterCollection

Tags: c#, sql, parameter-passing

Cannot figure out why I keep getting

> An SqlParameter with ParameterName is not contained by this
>   SqlParameterCollection

when I've been pulling and calling procs like this fine in other methods.

The proc does have the one param @EqId in that casing.

```
List<string> equipTypes = new List<string>();

Database db = DatabaseFactory.CreateDatabase("OurDBName");
DbCommand cmd = db.GetStoredProcCommand("Get_EquipTypes_By_ID");

db.DiscoverParameters(cmd);
cmd.Parameters["@EqId"].Value = equipID;

using (IDataReader objReader = db.ExecuteReader(cmd))
{
   while (objReader.Read())
      equipTypes.Add(DataUtility.GetStringFromReader(objReader, "Data"));
}
```

Comment: Why would you even use DiscoverParameters? That is an extra round trip, yet you already know the name. That is for tools that probe procs.

Answer (score 2):

Do your add parameters like this

```
 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EqId", equipID);
```

I thinks it's the cleanest way to do it, well kind of :)

Answer (score 0):

First off, I would not discover parameters when you are aware of the parameters. Since you are doing this, examine the parameter collection and make sure the parameter is being discovered. Fater you have that figured out, I would aim for something more like what Greg has suggested.